# What is the fastest way to start playing audio in QT application

Tags: qt, portaudio

I am developing an application in which i have a timeline which represents a song and I can put some effects to it. By moving the effect the song should start playing from specific time. I tried to use QMediaPlayer and that would be fine but when I move the effect, playback doesnt start immediately and that is the problem. There is just a very little delay but it is a problem in this case. I tried to look for the answers and I found some topics about low latency audio. I tried to implement Portaudio but I am pretty lost using it and even when I dont know if that would help.

Can somebody please give me some advice what should I use or what should I focus on?

Thank you.

```
TimelineWidget::TimelineWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{

    m_mediaPlayer = new QMediaPlayer(NULL, QMediaPlayer::LowLatency);
    m_mediaPlayer->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/Users/simonvaros/Desktop/hudba.wav"));
    m_effect = QRect(0, 0, 100, height());
    m_grab = false;
    m_effectWidth = m_effect.width();
    m_dif = 0;
    m_pos = 0;
    m_lastTime = QTime::currentTime();

}

void TimelineWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::paintEvent(event);

    QPainter p (this);
    QPen pen = QPen();

    QRect outline = QRect(0, 0, width() - 1, height() - 1);
    p.setPen(pen);
    p.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("white")));
    p.drawRect(outline);
    p.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("red")));
    p.drawRect(m_effect);
}

void TimelineWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(event);

    m_grab = false;
}

void TimelineWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);

    int pos = event->pos().x();

    if (pos > m_effect.x() && pos < m_effect.x() + m_effect.width())
    {
        m_grab = true;
        m_dif = pos - m_effect.x();
    }
}

void TimelineWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);

    if (m_grab)
    {
        m_pos = event->pos().x();
        m_effect.setX(m_pos - m_dif);

        m_mediaPlayer->setPosition((double)(m_pos / width()) * m_mediaPlayer->duration());
        m_mediaPlayer->play();

        m_effect.setWidth(m_effectWidth);
    }

    repaint();

}


#include <QWidget>
#include <QMediaPlayer>


class TimelineWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TimelineWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

private:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);



    QMediaPlayer *m_mediaPlayer;
    QRect m_effect;
    bool m_grab;
    int m_effectWidth;
    int m_dif;
    double m_pos;


signals:

public slots:

};
```

Comment: Merlinko, share your code for the player and the effect. Are you feeding the player directly from file ? did you try to buffer the music first and start player from buffer?

Comment: I edited my post and added my full test code. How can I put it to buffer before?

Answer (score 1):

First, invoking the QMediaPlayer with "LowLatency", is not meant for music, it is only for beeps, ringtones .. this is stated in QT documentation.

> QMediaPlayer::LowLatency | 0x01 | The player is expected to be used
>   with  simple audio formats, but playback should start without
>   significant delay.  Such playback service can be used for beeps,
>   ringtones, etc.

So you need to instantiate with `QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback`

Here is code sample how to invoke QMediaPlayer from a buffer:

```
    player =  new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::StreamPlayback);
    QFile file("/Users/simonvaros/Desktop/hudba.wav");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QByteArray *ba = new QByteArray();
    ba->append(file.readAll());
    QBuffer *buffer = new QBuffer(ba);
    buffer->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    buffer->reset();  // same as buffer.seek(0);
    qDebug() << "Buffer size:" << buffer->size(); // is the file loaded
    player->setMedia(QMediaContent(), buffer);
    player->play();
```

Comment: It looks good but it does not work actually :/ the music just does not play

Comment: Merlinko, It works at my side with an MP3 music! can you for testing purpose load an mp3 music and see. Also, change the player instance and remove "LowLatency" even in your original code and check

Comment: And one thing i probably did not mention properly, I need to use method set position because the music will be played from different position. Will that method work like this? It should, right?

Comment: Yes I did exactly the same as you wrote and it just does not work. I think the buffer is set correctly but probably the media is not set properly but im just guessing.

Comment: Which version of Qt and  QMultimedia is installed ? can you show your .h file

Comment: I am using QT 5.8, but i dont know how to get qmultimedia version... and i edit the main question and put there .h file

Comment: Could you rather show me your version how it works? :)

Comment: so did you include the #include <QBuffer> in your CPP file? are you getting project compiled with no errors?

Comment: Same code that I shared runs in my application. except last line (player.play()) should be a pointer (player->play())

Comment: Yes I have it included in cpp file. i get no errors

Comment: I am using Qt 5.9x , I dont know if that could be an issue at your side, but I don't think so

Comment: When you run the application, it reports the buffer size [qDebug() << "Buffer size:" << buffer->size();] , are you getting output there in your debugger screen ?

Comment: Is there any possibility that you could send me the whole project that works? i am really curious about this.

Comment: Yes I am getting that output

Comment: Or can you tell me what operating system you use?

Comment: I am using windows10. yes i can share the whole thing

Comment: okay you dont have to we found out that on win it works and on mac it does not :D this is so sad thank you for help

Comment: No actually it does not. I found somewhere that it is a bug... :/ So I am going to use it through objective c

Comment: I guess its also simple to give a try with any class that derives QIoDevice .. I would think of a socket ..